# How can i install Sphinx for Mac Os Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sphinx

I want to install latest stable version of Sphinx ([sphinxsearch.com](http://sphinxsearch.com/)) on Mac OS X Lion. What is a right way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is short guide, http://pat.github.com/ts/en/installing_sphinx.html its regarding thinking_sphinx, ruby gem for workign with rails, but it covers also installing sphinx server.

Answer (score 7):

I just checked and it's on brew, so you can just run if you have HomeBrew:
`brew install sphinx`.

Comment: I did "brew install sphinx" but when I try something like "make html" then it says the sphinx-build command was not found and that the SPHINXBUILD environment variable must point to the full path of the sphinx-build executable. Where is that?

Answer (score 3):

What wasn't obvious from those instructions was that the main executables would be found in /usr/local/bin/searchd and /usr/local/bin/indexer... I was a bit puzzled after install when I couldn't find anything *sphinx* in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the easy Install.

-Open your terminal.
-Execute the following command: sudo easy_install sphinx

Then it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Installed it in /usr/local/bin for me.